# Using integration by parts to find conditional expectation

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, integral

I am trying to evaluate the following expectation. The solution gives a hint to use integration by parts, but I do not see how it can be useful here. Could someone please explain how it can be used?

Let $X_{t} = e^{at} \left( X_{0} + \int_{0}^{t} e^{-as} dB_{s} \right)$. Find $E[X_{t}|\mathcal{F}_{s}]$ and $E[X_{t}^{2}|\mathcal{F}_{s}]$ for $s \leq t$.

$B_{s}$ is a standart Brownian motion with $\mathcal{N}(0,s)$ distribution. s,t are time increment, expectation is conditional on sigma-algebra.

Comment: perhaps look at $d(e^{-at}X_t)$